# Is there a way to make `open -a` pass command line arguments to the app it launches?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'd like to run [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) from the command line with some arguments.

```
$ open -a openscad myfile.scad
```

works as I expect.

```
$ open -a openscad --args --help
```

reports

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/OpenSCAD.app with error -10810.
```

when OpenSCAD is not already running.  When OpenSCAD is already running, then `open -a openscad --args --help` simply brings OpenSCAD to the foreground.

What I really need is for this to work:

```
$ open -a openscad --args -o myfile.stl myfile.scad
```

which works just like my previous example.  What should I do to launch OpenSCAD with command line arguments?

Before hitting submit I reproduced my questions for pasting here, and I found a solution that more-or-less works.  All of these seem to do what I expect, even if OpenSCAD is not already running.

```
$ /Applications/OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD --help
$ /Applications/OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD --args --help
$ /Applications/OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD -o ball.stl ball.scad
$ /Applications/OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD --args -o ball.stl ball.scad
```

Still, is there a way to make `open -a` pass command line arguments to the app it launches?

Comment: I don't have openscad. But have you tried to open -a openscad --args '--help' or open -a openscad --args "--help"

Comment: I didn't see change in behaviour by adding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can get to work is opening a file. It seems that the App is not made to accept the args this way.

```
open -a openscad --args '/path/to/foo.scad'
```

The App does have an Applescript scripting definition but it only has `reload` defined.